# Error: minSdk version 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

That's the error that I get in my project.. can anyone help me.

[minsdkerror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBonH.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [10.2.0 release notes](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_2017_-_v102) and  [this blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/11/google-play-services-and-firebase-for-android-will-support-api-level-14-at-minimum.html):

> Version 10.0.0 of the Google Play services client libraries, as well as the Firebase client libraries for Android, will be the last version of these libraries that support Android API level 9 (Android 2.3, Gingerbread). The next scheduled release of these libraries, version 10.2.0, will increase the minimum supported API level from 9 to 14 (Android 4.0.1, Ice Cream Sandwich).

As you are using 10.2.0, the minSdkVersion is now 14. You must use 10.0.1 or earlier if you want to support down to API 9 devices.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help!

Comment: If this answered your question, make sure to accept the answer to remove it from the queue of unanswered questions. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

Google Play Service `10.2.0` dropped support for Gingerbread and only supports API 14 and up now so if you need to support older devices then you need to stay at 10.0

Comment: Thanks for the help!